How render proper Linear Rec.709 Gamma 2.4?
I have a task to render out PNG 16 bit in Linear Rec.709 Gamma 2.4 and can`t figure out if I do it in proper way. Is it enough to set view transform to Raw and Gamma 2.4 in color management panel? Or it should be made with compositor? 

You could render in openexr which is always linear and use your compositor of choice to change the color profile

Yeah, I tied this way.  But I`m trying to find the way to render it in one pass so that it doesn't take up much space, because of big resolution.
